# How to wrapped JSON Handler in Function

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire

So I'm using this function to pass the JSON Value **(Any Object)** in other class but it's full of issues so I can't get it working

```
func getSWPeopleAPI() -> NSMutableArray {
    var JSON2: NSMutableArray
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://swapi.co/api/people/1").responseJSON { Response in
        print(Response.request)
        print(Response.response)
        print(Response.data)
        print(Response.result)
        if let JSON = Response.result.value{
            JSON2 = JSON as! NSMutableArray
        }
        else{
            return
        }

    }
    return JSON2
}
```

Do you have a suggestion on how can I achieve this to pass it to my ApiManagerClass and what data type is best use when dealing with JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing in a wrong way! `JSON` must have a type of `NSDictionary`.

```
func getSWPeopleAPI(strUrl: String, completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) -> (){

    Alamofire.request(.GET, strUrl).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .Success(let data):
            let json = data as? NSDictionary
            completionHandler(json, nil)
        case .Failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
```

Here is the code with completion handler and error as specified!

> How to Use:

```
postWebserviceWithURL(Url!) { (responseData, error) -> () in

   //Code
}
```

Comment: may I ask what's the difference of using Response instead or response?

Comment: You can put any name there! But as far as I know the `Response` keyword is reserved! So, better to user any other name.

Comment: oh! thanks for that Info. I'm new to swift I'm used to OBJ-C can I ask if how can I  all that func properly?

Comment: I can't quite understand that part on how to use it but this is what I've done it so far it's working :D

swApiHandler.getSWPeopleAPI("http://swapi.co/api/people/1", completionHandler: {response, error in
            print(response!.description)
    })

Comment: It's perfect! You can use it anyway!

Comment: cool! thanks for your help @Sohil :D Now I'll try to use SwiftyJson goodluck to me :D thanks again!